# Showing units sold in product page OpenCartv3

Tags: php, database, opencart, opencart-3

I'm trying to show the units sold for each product in Product page in OpenCart v3 but I keep getting the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getUnitsSold()
>   on null in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store/catalog/controller/product/product.php:157
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store/system/engine/action.php(79):
>   ControllerProductProduct->index() #1
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store/catalog/controller/startup/router.php(25):
>   Action->execute(Object(Registry)) #2
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store/system/engine/action.php(79):
>   ControllerStartupRouter->index() #3
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store/system/engine/router.php(67):
>   Action->execute(Object(Registry)) #4
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store/system/engine/router.php(56):
>   Router->execute(Object(Action)) #5
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store/system/framework.php(168):
>   Router->dispatch(Object(Action), Object(Action)) #6
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store/system/startup.php(104):
>   require_once('/Applications/X...') #7
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store/index.php(19): in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/store/catalog/controller/product/product.php
>   on line 157

What I have so far is

catalog/model/catalog/product.php

```
public function getUnitsSold($product_id) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(op.quantity) AS total FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "order_product` op LEFT JOIN `" . DB_PREFIX . "order` o ON (op.order_id = o.order_id) WHERE o.order_status_id > '0' AND op.product_id = '" . (int)$product_id . "'");
if ($query->row) {
        return $query->row['total'];
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

and in catalog/controller/product/product.php

```
$data['text_units_sold'] = $this->language->get('text_units_sold');
$this->data['units_sold'] = $this->model_catalog_product->getUnitsSold($product_id);
```

Anyone can detect what is the problem and the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that in the function where you are calling getUnitsSold, you have not done a

```
$this->load->model('catalog/product');
```

Comment: It works!!! Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it. I have been scratching my brain for hours.